# Identity of recently added record and insert from gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, insert, datatable

I am developing an ASP.Net VB Web Application

The application contains a `GridView` which displays the records of a user table from my created datable. The database is an Sql server database.

The code below inserts data into one table and through the built in function `@@Identity` to insert the most recently added record id (`tt_id`) from the `trainingTbl` table and inserting that record id into the `userAssessmentTbl`. Adding the identity to the second `userAssessmentTbl` table works fine.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim lblUsr2 As Control = FindControlRecursive(MultiTabs, "txtUsr")
        Dim strQuery As String
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand

        strQuery = "Insert into trainingTbl(s_id, t_date, EditorId, wa_id, st_id) values(@s_id , @t_date, @EditorId, @wa_id, @st_id  ) Insert into userAssessmentTbl(tt_id, UserId) values(@@Identity, @UserId)"

        cmd = New SqlCommand(strQuery)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_id", DDLCourse.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t_date", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EditorId", User.Identity.Name.ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st_id", myLblStation.Value().ToString)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wa_id", myLblWatch.Value().ToString)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", lblUsr2.UniqueID.ToString)
        InsertUpdateData(cmd)
    End Sub
```

The issue I’m having seems to be centered on how I insert a `uniqueidenifier` from a `GridView` into a `userAssessmentTbl` database!

And how, I guess using a loop I can insert the UserId records from that Gridview (`GridView1`) into the `userAssessmentTbl` table along with the looped id from the `@@Identity`.

This part of the insert parameter seems to be incorrect:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", lblUsr2.UniqueID().ToString)
```

And the error I’m met with is: '*Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.*'

I’ve also tried it like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value().ToString()
```

And im met with the error: *'Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier'*

**The qusetion has slightly changed to how do I Insert a String into SQL DB Where DataType Is Uniqueidentifier?**

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all:

> `@@IDENTITY` [returns the most recently](http://cgaskell.wordpress.com/2006/11/15/using-identity-vs-scope_identity-and-further-implications-with-triggers/) created identity for your current
>   connection, not necessarily the identity for the recently added row in
>   a table. **Always use** `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` **to return the identity of the
>   recently added row.**

---

**Secondly**, to asnwer your question:

The SQL type `Uniqueidentifier` and the CLR type `Guid` match up.

So instead of passing `"@UserId"` in as a parameter you need to create a `Guid` out of the string value.

```
Dim userID As Guid = New Guid(lblUsr2.UniqueID.ToString)
```

Comment: Thanks the first part of your answer was great and the second part helped me on my way.